# редирект location

Tags: nginx

К примеру у меня имеется два `location`:

```
location /tmp/ {
  try_files $uri @named;
}

location @named {
  internal;
  ...
}
```

Как видим все запросы редиректятся к именованному местоположению, но меня смущает использование `try_files` для редиректа, так как при использовании этой директивы будут сначала проверены файлы по соответсвующему пути и только после этого будет выполнен internal redirect. Как можно осуществить редирект без использования `try_files`?

Comment: А цель в чём? Что бы все запросы в `/tmp/...` сразу оказывались в `@named`? А там что? Может проще конфиг из `@named` перетащить в `/tmp/`?

Comment: @AlexeyTen цель вы верно определили, но перетащить конфиг из `@named` в `/tmp` нельзя (точнее нежелательно). Суть в том, что в `@named` помещена логика обработки, а `/tmp` предоставляет доступ "снаружи" к этой логике. Тобишь `@named` может быть использован в множестве других местоположений, которые будут разнится по ограничениям и доступу. Надеюсь понятно сформулировал задачу...

Comment: Ну можно просто вместо `$uri` использовать что-то точно не существующее. `try_files /NOT_EXIST @named;`

Comment: @AlexeyTen да, верно подмечено, но все же: есть ли способ не на основе `try_files`?

Comment: Ну например так `error_page 555 = @named; return 555;`

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/787065/211028

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо за ссылку. Что касается `error_page` - по-видимому переменные (например `$info "info";`), определенные в `location /tmp`, не передаются (расшариваются) в `@named`. Почему в этом плане `try_files` отличается от `error_page`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108825/discussion-between-alexey-ten-and-andrej-levkovitch).